Underlying Foundations of Category Morphism Definition
Recently I'm studying category theory in the beginning level. This mathematical concept is really fantastic. However, the definition of morphism composition seems a little confusing:
$$\circ: \mathrm{Hom}_c(B,C) × \mathrm{Hom}_c(A,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}_x(A,B)$$
In ordinary function composition, we usually use $f \circ g (x)$ to express $f(g(x))$. Morphism composition, however, seems to be defined in a reverse order. This seems to be contradictory with intuitions and conservations. With this definition, one must use contravariance functor to describe a cast from a space to its dual.
When a definition in mathematical seems to be odd, most the case there are some underlying structures/rules/properties that indicating this oddity. Or at least, it will make solving problems easier in some ways. Can you give me a hint or guess for this oddity?
This is my first question in stackexchange and I'm not native English speaker, forgive me if I did some mistakes.

"Morphism composition, however, seems to be defined in a reverse order."
Is it? Take $(f,g) \in \mathrm{Hom}_c(B,C) × \mathrm{Hom}_c(A,B)$. Then $g : A \to B$ and $f : B \to C$ as morphisms, and hence $f \circ g : A \to C$. Maybe I'm missing something but this doesn't appear to be "backwards" to me.

$\circ \colon \mathrm{Hom}_c(B,C) \times \mathrm{Hom}_c(A,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}_c(A,B)$ is the function defined by $\circ((f,g)) = f \circ g$ for all $(f,g) \in \mathrm{Hom}_c(B,C) \times \mathrm{Hom}_c(A,B)$.

There is a truly unfortunate notational issue here. Normally, if $f : A \to B$ is a map of sets, and $g : B \to C$ is another map of sets, then their composition
$$A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$$
is a map traditionally written $g \circ f : A \to C$. This is because traditionally we write functions taking inputs from the right, so with this convention $(g \circ f)(a) = g(f(a))$ for $a \in A$.
But note that there is a tension between this convention and the convention to write $f : A \to B$, with the domain on the left and the codomain on the right! This is entirely a historical accident, but it forces on us an annoying choice: should we say that composition of functions (and, generally, composition in a category) is a function
$$\circ : \text{Hom}(A, B) \times \text{Hom}(B, C) \to \text{Hom}(A, C)$$
or should we say that it's a function
$$\circ : \text{Hom}(B, C) \times \text{Hom}(A, B) \to \text{Hom}(A, C)?$$
Either way conflicts with at least one standard convention. If we pick the first convention (which is standard, as far as I know) then $g \circ f$ is the result of composition applied to the ordered pair $(f, g)$, but if we pick the second convention (which is the one you're looking at, although I've personally never seen it before) then composition sends a pair of a function $B \to C$ and a function $A \to B$ to a function $A \to C$, and now the domains and codomains look all wonky.
In some contexts it makes sense to deal with this issue by insisting on writing compositions in diagrammatic order, which means to write the composite $A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$ as $f \circ g$ rather than the usual $g \circ f$, and to place inputs to functions on the left.
In any case, this is a purely notational issue; just remember that composition of morphisms in a category is supposed to straightforwardly generalize composition of functions, it's not supposed to be something foreign.

Although it's quite rare (and I would say bad) to write $f\circ g$ to mean $g\circ f$, it's quite common these days to write it as $f\mathrel{;}g$ or $f\mathrel{⨟}g$ or sometimes $fg$.

If $A,B,C$ are sets and $f:B\to C$, $g:A\to B$, are functions, then their composition
$$C\xleftarrow f B \xleftarrow g A $$
is a function $(f\circ g):A\to C$. This also happens if $A,B,C$ are objects of a category and $f,g$ are morphisms. Does this help?
